Similar questions
Some of you may have noticed recently I have started asking questions on translation a lot. Is this alright to ask questions of the same topic so many times? Or should I ask different questions?

With regards to the asking multiple questions on similar topics, that's fine---many people do this.  Thanks for your contribution.  This is just how people are: they become interested in a topic, and ask a bunch of questions about it in one go.  This only becomes a problem if you're obstructing others from participating, and I don't believe you're anywhere near this.  In any case, we're all limited to 6 questions per day, although it's very hard to hit that limit.
Sometimes I have a bunch of questions, so I save them as a text file on my computer and ask them at about 1 or 2 per day.  Perhaps the answer to one question helps answer another.
What I'd like to draw attention to is that a translation request, like How to say subject–verb–object (SVO) in Chinese?, would generally be closed using this reason:

Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.

What "prior research effort is clearly indicated" usually means in practice is "explain why e.g. Google Translate doesn't answer the question" (this way answers are not simply copy/pasted from Google Translate, which doesn't help anyone, and it helps answerers better understand where the OP is stuck).
Your case is somewhat unusual in that you've answered your own question, and it's not clear whether or not that should count as "prior research effort".

Sorry about that unclear question, I have edited it - should I not answer my own questions then? Thanks

You can answer your own questions; that's why there's an "Answer your own question" button there.  Sometimes I find it useful for those questions I intend to ask, then after a bit more research I find the answer.
